# copyToRealmOrUpdate and Delete

Tags: android, performance, realm

I need to synchronize the data in my application. I do the request to the server, bind and use `copyToRealmOrUpdate(Iterable<E> objects)` to add or update this data to the database.

But my files can be invalidated and I need something to delete everything that don't have at the data that return at the request. I don't want to truncate or do a manual delete to do this because performance matters.

#### IDEA 1

`@beeender`

What do you think about use the PRIMARY_KEY of the table to delete the data that I don't want (or I don't need)?

Looks like:

- 1º: If the database was populated, get all primary key and add it in an `HashMap` (or anything that do the same).
- 2º: Update the data or add, removes the item of the `HashMap` (using the primary key) if it was updated or added.
- 3º: Remove all items of `HashMap` on the Realm.

Comment: Honestly, if you need to delete everything you had previously, just call `clear()` like `realm.where(XYZ.class).clear()` at the start of your transaction and bam!

Comment: I don't want remove everything It's an unecessary work. I only want remove the data that don't have been added or updated.
Performance matters.

Comment: It's slower to determine what has been updated and what not than to clear everything.

Comment: Ok, look to this case: I've 16000 items to save and one item to delete. It's faster to delete all and remove one item? It's correct?

Comment: A lot of items isn't changed, then, I can jump this unnecessary interaction :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the `In memory Realm` would be a good choice for you in this situation. You can find related documents [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#in-memory-realm) .

By using the in-memory Realm:

- The db will be empty when you start a new app process
- After you close all the instances of the Realm, the data will be cleared as well.

----------------------------------- *Update for deleting data for normal case* -----------------------------------------

For deleting, there are some options you can use

1. Remove all data for a specific model, see [doc](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html#clear())

   `realm.allObjects(MyModel.class).clear();`
2. Remove entire data from a given Realm by (Realm API)[https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#deleteRealm(io.realm.RealmConfiguration)] (close all instances first!):

   `Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfig);`
3. Or just remove the Realm file through normal java API.

If you really care about the performance, you could consider to separate those data in one Realm, and use option 2 or 3 to remove them. See doc [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#configuring-a-realm) for using different Realm through `RealmConfiguration`.

----------------------------------- *Update for delete by Date field* ------------------------------------------------------

For your user case, this would be a good choice:

1. Add a `Date` field to your model, and add annotation `@Index` to make query faster on it.
2. Update/add rows and set the modified date to current time.
3. Delete the objects where its `modifiedDate` is before the current date.`realm.where(MyModel.class).lessThan("modifiedDate", currentDate).findAll().clear()`

**NOTE: "The dates are truncated with a precision of one second. In order to maintain compatibility between 32 bits and 64 bits devices, it is not possible to store dates before 1900-12-13 and after 2038-01-19."** See [current limitations](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#current-limitations). If you could modified the table in a very short time which the accuracy doesn't fit, consider to use a `int` field instead. You can get the column's max value by [`RealmResult.max()`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html#max(java.lang.String))

Comment: But I need to save the data for offline usage. :(

Comment: Updated the answer :)